# mvc3 jqbargraph vertical axis overlapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqbargraph

I'm using jqbargraph to show data from a Model, it's working fine but the axis values are overlapping.. is there a way to show them as Vertical so they will take less space ?

i checked the jqbargraph properties but there is no specific property to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqbargraph adds a class to each label that is "graphLabel" + id of the element you added the graph to.  For example if you do:

```
$('#divForGraph').jqBarGraph({ data: arrayOfData });
```

the class of the labels will be `.graphLabeldivForGraph`

So, you can transform those labels with css

```
.graphLabeldivForGraph {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:5px;
}
```